How to filter entity based on non-assosiated entity in sequelize
I can't filter Kase based on non-assosiated KaseColorLocation inStock property.
Kase entity belongs to many Color through KaseColor
Color entity belongs to many Kase through KaseColor
KaseColorLocation entity belongs to KaseColor and Location which are solving many to many relation
const cases1 = await db.Kase.findAll({
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: db.Color,
                            as: 'colors',
                        },
                        {
                            model: db.Location,
                            as: 'locations',
                            where: {
                                name: location
                            },
                            through: {
                                where: {
                                    visible: true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });

Kase.associate = function (models) {
        Kase.belongsToMany(models.KaseType, {
            through: models.KaseKaseType,
            foreignKey: 'kaseId',
            as: 'caseTypes'
        });
        Kase.belongsToMany(models.Location, {
            through: models.KaseLocation,
            foreignKey: 'kaseId',
            as: 'locations'
        });
        Kase.belongsToMany(models.Color, {
            through: models.KaseColor,
            foreignKey: 'kaseId',
            as: 'colors'
        });
        Kase.belongsToMany(models.PromoCode, {
            through: models.KasePromoCode,
            foreignKey: 'kaseId',
            as: 'promoCodes'
        });
        Kase.belongsTo(models.Serie, {foreignKey: 'serieId'});
    };

Color.associate = function (models) {
    Color.belongsToMany(models.Kase, {
      through: models.KaseColor,
      foreignKey: 'colorId'
    });
    Color.hasMany(models.KaseColor, {foreignKey: 'colorId', as: 'kaseColors'});
  }
  return Color;

KaseColorLocation.associate = function (models) {
        KaseColorLocation.belongsTo(models.Location, {
            foreignKey: 'locationId',
            targetKey: 'id'
          });
        KaseColorLocation.belongsTo(models.KaseColor, {
        foreignKey: 'kaseColorId',
        targetKey: 'id'
        });
      }
    return KaseColorLocation;

KaseColor.associate = function(models) {
    KaseColor.hasMany(models.KaseImage, {foreignKey: 'kaseColorId', as: 'images'});
    KaseColor.belongsTo(models.Color, {foreignKey: 'colorId'})
    KaseColor.belongsTo(models.Kase, {foreignKey: 'kaseId'})
    KaseColor.belongsToMany(models.Location, {
      through: models.KaseColorLocation,
      foreignKey: 'kaseColorId',
      as: 'locations'
    });
    KaseColor.hasMany(models.KaseColorLocation, {as:'kaseColorLocations', foreignKey:'kaseColorId'});
    KaseColor.belongsTo(models.Color, {
      foreignKey: 'colorId',
      targetKey: 'id'
    });
  };
  return KaseColor;

I have tried this, but I am sure it's not the case:
const cases1 = await db.Kase.findAll({
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: db.Color,
                            as: 'colors',
                            include: [
                                {
                                    model: db.KaseColor,
                                    as: 'kaseColors',
                                    include: [
                                        {
                                            model: db.KaseColorLocation,
                                            as: 'kaseColorLocations',
                                            where: {
                                                inStock: true,
                                                // kaseColorId: db.Sequelize.col('colors.kaseColors.id') // Ensure matching kaseColorId
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            model: db.Location,
                            as: 'locations',
                            where: {
                                name: location
                            },
                            through: {
                                where: {
                                    visible: true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });

